# How to join tables on column containing text

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables to merge:

t1

```
Continent    Country     City
-----------------------
Europe      Germany      Munich

NA          Canada       Ontario

Asia        Singapore    (blank)

Asia        Japan        Tokyo
```

AND

t2

```
Country      Status
-----------------
Germany      Complete

Canada       Incomplete

Singapore    Complete

Japan        Complete
```

I want to get the continent with 2nd highest "Complete" status. I am new to SQL and I am trying hard to learn the basics, but I cannot get this done.

Comment: how do you decide which country is the second highest complete

Comment: What do you mean by merge? It's not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: Welcome to SO! "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" is important. We need to see what you've tried so we can avoid repeating your tracks. Where did you research this? Why didn't it help? If it did did you write code? If not why? If so, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered? Without that it looks like you didn't try and want us to write the code for you.

Comment: This is tagged [tag:sequel] however you're asking for raw SQL. Do you want to know how to use Sequel, or not know that it's the wrong tag?

Answer (score 0):

I understand you mean the country with more cities with status complete. You can use sub-queries:

```
with a as
(
select a.country,
sum(case when status = 'Complete' then 1 else 0 end) as CompleteCount 
from t1 a inner join t2 b on a.country = b.country
group by a.country
)

select country from
(
select country, 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY CompleteCount  desc) as OrderComplete
from a
)a where OrderComplete = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to pull out the continent that has the second most country marked as completed.

If so, you can join, aggregate, order by the count of completed countries per continent, and then filter on the second rows:

```
select continent
from 
    (select distinct country, continent from t2) t2
    inner join t1 on t1.country = t2.country
group by continent
order by sum(case when status = 'Complete' then 1 else 0 end) desc
limit 1, 1
```

Note the use of `distinct` when retrieving the association of countries and continents: this is because your sample data seems like it could have more than one row per country/continent tuple (since it is referencing cities). Without the `distinct`, we would potientally generate duplicate rows, causing `sum()` to be wrong.